# wildcard in R pattern

Tags: r, regex, string, list, pattern-matching

Hy guys, 
I have a list of files which start with an "s" and some of them end 
with an "m" while others with an "i".
I would like just to get the ones finishing with "m" however this command does not work.

```
list=list.files(path="~/Deduplicated_input",pattern="^sorted_deduplicated_sorted*m$", full.names=TRUE)
```

What do you think?

Comment: Try `^sorted_deduplicated_sorted.*m$`

Comment: Are these BAM files? Either way, you should provide the whole file extension in your pattern, e.g. `\\.bam$`.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern must be a [regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) so .* rather than *, i.e.

```
list.files(path = "~/Deduplicated_input",
           pattern = "^sorted_deduplicated_sorted.*m$", 
           full.names = TRUE)
```

or to use a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), convert it to a regular expression like this:

```
list.files(path = "~/Deduplicated_input",
           pattern = glob2rx("sorted_deduplicated_sorted*m"), 
           full.names = TRUE)
```